# print a variable from function to a textbox in windows form (c++/CLI)

Tags: windows, forms, c++-cli

Hi i have a program that normally runs under console, now i have to make it a user's interface.

So i made a new project (Windows forms) and start adding the headers .h and .cpp onto it from my program that contains the console program.

I need to print a variable from a header into a textbox in windows form. Here is my code:

This is the variable i need to print **meaning**

*test.h*

```
string **meaning**;
```

*On the test.cpp:*

```
void Engine::Conclude(void)
string Name;
**meaning**= assignmeaning(Name)
cout<<"" <<"->"<<**meaning**;
```

CWorkspace.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "WorkSpace.h"
using namespace std;

CWorkspace::CWorkspace()
    {
        m_pBuilder= new Compiler();

    }

void CWorkspace::LoadKnowledge()
{
CPROPNode* Arbol=Builder->SyntacticTree;
   /*This is not relevant*/
fstream file("..\\Text.txt", ios::in);
        if(file.is_open())
        {
            if(Builder->Compiler(file))
            {
                cout<<" ok"<<endl;
           /*Motor is a local variable from CWorkspace*/

    Motor = new InferenceEngine(Builder->SyntacticTree,Builder); 
    if(Motor->ValidateKnowledge())
        {}
}
}
```

So i tried on my textbox to do this:

```
#include test.h
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace std;
namespace mainForm
{ 
  public ref class Res: public System::Windows::Forms::Form
   {
     public:
        CWorkspace* Workspace;
              Res(void)
                  {
                     InitializeComponent();
                  }

/*
  /*
    /*Auto generated code from windows form*/
                                            */
                                             */
private: System::Void Resultado_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

string s = Workspace->Motor->meaning;
             String^ hola = gcnew String(s.cstr());
             textBox1->Text= hola;
```

but somehow i cannot compile, anyone know how to write this variable on a textbox?

this is the error i get when compiling:

**error C2039: 'cstr':is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>**

Althoug i dont know if this is the correct way to print a variable.

Comment: This is C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: Should we gaze into our crystal balls to know how it doesn't compile? You didn't post a compilable sample, so it's your responsibility to provide us with compiler output.

Comment: What are *Workspace* and *Motor*, it they are **namespace** and **type** you should write: **Workspace::Motor::meaning**.

Comment: sorry edited, *Workspace* is a .cpp and *Motor* is contained insder Worskpace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the std::string method is [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). You're missing the underscore.